# Do whole number solutions exist for $3x^2 = y^2$?

Tags: square-numbers

I am investigating properties of square numbers and would like to find whole number solutions for this equation

$3x^2 = y^2$

or $\sqrt{3x^2} = y$

How do I prove that whole number solutions do not exist or how do I identify them?

Comment: Hint:  $3$ divides the left hand an odd number of times, what about the right?

Comment: Zero counts as a whole number.  Other than that ... oh well.

Comment: I should have mentioned Non Zero solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1.$ Using the FTA approach: Power of three is odd on the left side while even on that of the right side.

$2.$ $3x^2=y^2\implies \frac{y}{x}=\sqrt{3}$ LHS is rational while RHS is irrational. (This is the same approach as previous one but a bit easy to understand).

Comment: therefore does this prove you can never have a magic square of square numbers?

Comment: That is a 3x3 magic square of squared numbers

Comment: But you use division and so lose the solution x=y=0.

Comment: You're missing the solution $x=y=0$, @OscarLanzi - beat me to it!

Comment: Ha ha didn't notice that OP asked for whole number solutions, anyways other answers have pointed that out $x=y=0$ :-)  is the only whole number solution

Answer (score 3):

We can rearrange this to get

\begin{align}3x^2&=y^2\\
y&=\pm\sqrt{3x^2}\\
&=\pm\sqrt{3}x\end{align}

If we assume $x$ is a whole number, then $y$ can only be a whole number if $x=y=0$

Equally:

\begin{align}3x^2&=y^2\\
x^2&=\frac {y^2}{3}\\
x&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{y^2}{3}}\\
&=\pm\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}\end{align}

Again, if we assume $y$ is a whole number, then $x$ can only be a whole number if $x=y=0$

Therefore the only solution for $x$ and $y$ whole numbers is $x=y=0$

Answer (score 3):

Actually, yes.  Remember that zero is a whole number and identify the one solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

- Since $x$ is a whole number, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ is also a whole number.
- $\sqrt{3x^2} = \sqrt 3\cdot\sqrt{x^2}$,
- $\sqrt{3}$ is not a rational number.